# Why does nav not work on internal static pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have the most peculiar problem with Wordpress currently. I have loaded a template as a theme for a client website. Everything's working great. But when I create an interior page, the Nav seems to be stop working. When I click on the logo on the nav, it go back to home page, it works. But the other links in the nav stops working. If I right click and "open new tab" it works. Even when I change the URL in the inspector, the link does not work.

Working site: `www.businessgroupresources.com`.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably because you have the same thing on the main page and on the internal pages: "../#workplace". This works on the main page but for internal pages it needs to be something else.